# Duda en construccion de una ruta Login en Flask

Tags: python, flask

Estoy trabajando con un login en flask, estoy viendo un tutorial, tengo todo este código:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login_page():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():                    
        attempted_user = Users.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()      

        if attempted_user and attempted_user.check_password_correction(                  
            attempted_password=form.password.data
        ):
           login_user(attempted_user)     
           flash(f'Iniciaste como : {attempted_user.username}', category='sucess') 
           return redirect(url_for('market_page'))     
        else:
            flash('Usuario y clave no coinciden', category='danger')   

    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

entiendo todo excepto la parte del login_user(attempted_user), que hace esta funcion exactamente?

Comment: La función `login_user` es parte del módulo `flask-login` que proporciona todas las funcionalidades para manejar las sesiones. En palabras simples, lo que hace esa función es guardar `attempted_user` como un usuario logeado o que ha iniciado sesión.

Comment: buena respuesta muchas gracias @Christian